# Как запретить горизонтальную прокрутку Вкладок?

Tags: java, android

Использую вкладки от material design , как запретить прокрутку вкладок ,чтоб они не крутились с одной на второй при движение пальцем на экране , а только при выборе переходил на вкладку

**UPD:**

Java ругается на метод

```
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

**xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.harrix.myapplication.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_home_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_3d_rotation_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp
    };

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }


    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ƏSAS");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "VIRTUAL TUR");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "ÜNVANIMIZ");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Pager:**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{
    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enabled ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enabled ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CustomViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{
    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enabled ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enabled ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

}
```

---

В разметке заменить

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
   ...
   />
```

на

```
<имя.пакета.CustomViewPager 
   ...
 />
```

---

Использовать:

```
mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28504193/2323537)

Comment: СЛушай открыть ноый клас там наследовать этот класс затем в своет классе прописать setPagign?&&&

Comment: можешь пояснее обьяснить?

Comment: @elik, этот класс тащите себе в проект, потом в коде используйте `setPagingEnabled(false)`, также нужно изменить pager в разметке, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо ща буду пробывать и спасибо за такой ответ он дал мне ответ сразу на несколько вопросо о реализациях классов .

Comment: не как не получается в чем проблема????  mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

Comment: java ругается на метоl

Comment: метод mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

Comment: @elik , Вероятно нужно добавить CustomViewPager mViewPager = (CustomViewPager ) findViewById(R.id.айди_на_разметке);

Comment: хмммм яж не назначил его костюм а взял базовый (((да?

Comment: как мне подтянуть знания   джава?с чего начать?

Comment: спасибо получилось